# How do I create my own localization for a plotly plot?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, internationalization

I have a shiny app with a plotly-plot. I want to change the language of that plot. Here is what they propose in the documentation:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)


ui <- fluidPage(
plotlyOutput("po")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$po <- renderPlotly({
N <- 100
plot_ly(type="scattergl",mode="markers", x=rnorm(100*N), y=rnorm(100*N)) %>% config(locale = "de")
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works for `locale = "de"` but not for `locale = "pl"`. The reason is (as far as I can tell) that in https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-de-latest.js the translations for words like "box select" is included, however for https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-pl-latest.js it only contains months and days of week.

The app is going to be translated into many languages, and I want to be able to control that it works in all of those. So my question is: How can I use my own dictionary instead of the standard locale dictionary in my plotly plot?

Comment: These files are a part of the Plotly package and are stored in your library. You can modify them and create new documents for any language that isn't already generated by Plotly.  To see where these are stored on your computer, use the base function `system.file`. For example, this is the location of the `de` or German: `system.file(package = "plotly","/htmlwidgets/lib/plotlyjs/locales/de.js")`.   If you want to see what words and phrases you need for the incomplete languages, you can parse a complete file, like German, and copy that data, less the German translations to another language file.